# How to sum up arrayed choiceBox<integer> value with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I think I wrote my Java code well but am still getting expection error.

This is the code:

All procedures met, let me go straight to the portion of the code with problem.

```
Int sumofc = 0;
VBox vlay = new VBox(10);

ChoiceBox<Integer> c1[]  = new ChoiceBox[10]
For (int x=0;x<10;x++){
    c1[x] = new ChoiceBox<>();
    C1[x].getItems().add(1);
    C1[x].getItems().add(2);
    C1[x].getItems().add(3);
    Vlay.getChildren().add(c1[x]);
    sumofc += c1[x].getValue();
}
```

The `sumofc` is not adding the values.

Comment: Those uppercase/lowercase mistakes are just typos I guess???

Comment: Knowing what you expect in `sumofc` would help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the values form the choice boxes before even adding them to the scene. This means the user has not interacted with the `ChoiceBox`es in any way. Instead you should read when the user interacts with the control in a meaningful way, e.g. by selecting a different value.

Furthermore the value selected by default is `null` which causes a `NullPointerException`, when you try to automatically unbox it, since it's equivalent to

```
sumofc += c1[x].getValue().intValue();
```

Considering these facts you could rewrite the code similar to this:

```
VBox vlay = new VBox(10);

ChoiceBox<Integer> c1[] = new ChoiceBox[10];

InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
    int sumofc = 0;
    for (ChoiceBox<Integer> cb : c1) {
        Integer value = cb.getValue();
        if (value != null) {
            sumofc += value;
        }
    }

    // do something with sumofc
    System.out.println(sumofc);
};

for (int x = 0; x < c1.length; x++) {
    c1[x] = new ChoiceBox<>();
    c1[x].getItems().addAll(1, 2, 3);
    vlay.getChildren().add(c1[x]);
    c1[x].valueProperty().addListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: If I use (my" sum the choice values btn")   like this:    btn.setOnAction(e -> system.out.println(c[0].getValues()+c[1].getValues())) outside the for loop it does the summing , but I want it to sum the array choiceBox values into an integer in the array